# SpringBootTest not resolving parent child relation - failed to lazy initialize

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using springBootTest to test a service I've created. In the before each function i create a parententity using the repository directly.

```
parentEntity = parentEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(ObjectMother.getParentEntityBuilder().string3("s3").build());
```

Within my test i create a childentity

```
childEntity = childEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(ObjectMother.getChildEntityBuilder().parentEntity(parentEntity).build());
```

The children relation is defined as follows

```
@Getter @Setter
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="PARENTENTITY_ID", updatable = false)
private Set<ChildEntity> children;
```

This is called within the test

```
parentEntity = parentEntityService.read(requestContext, parentEntity.getId());
parentEntity.getChildren().forEach(child -> Assert.assertNotNull(child.getText()));
```

It causes the following error

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sap.icn.pi.test.data.mcp.ParentEntity.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

If i add @Transactional to my test method i receive the following

```
java.lang.NullPointerException // for parentEntity.getChildren()
```

** Edit: Code Snippets **

```
@Test
public void get_children_through_parent() {
    parentEntity = parentEntityService.read(requestContext, 1);

    parentEntity.getChildren().forEach(child -> Assert.assertNotNull(child));
    parentEntity.getChildren().forEach(child -> Assert.assertNull(child.getTooltip()));
}
```

ParentEntity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PARENTENTITY")
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "idgen", sequenceName = "SEQ_PARENTENTITY")
@Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Localized
public class ParentEntity extends BaseEntity{

  ... //props

  @Getter @Setter
  @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name="PARENTENTITY_ID", updatable = false)
  private Set<ChildEntity> children;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common JPA/Hibernate problem. Object was read is different Hibernate session or hibernate session doesn't exist anymore, so lazy loading can't do SQL query to retrieve lazy dependency. Reason of this situation can vary and you didn't provide enough context.

To fix that, you have various options:

1. Make sure that object is read and lazy dependency is loaded in same Hibernate session. Spring Automatically creates hibernate session per controller request, so it would be good to make sure that you object is not retrieved in servlet filter and lazy dependency in your controller/service. Or common problem is also passing that object into separate thread.
2. Change dependency to be EAGER:

   ```
   @Getter @Setter
   @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="PARENTENTITY_ID", updatable = false)
   private Set<ChildEntity> children;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Suggestion 2 doesn't seem to be fitting because I do not want to change my fetchtype to eager only to be able to test it better.
How would i ensure the object is read within the same session. I'm basically just using my service layer functions.

Comment: Are you sharing them across various user requests?

Comment: Sharing what? Within as test i call  "e = myservice.read(...)" and after that "e.getChildren()" and that's basically it. I tried to add @Transactional to the test class, this will resolve the error, but getChildren will always return null then ...

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the code. Can you post relevant snippets?

Comment: Added a test call + the model